# Why do non-native English users often spell "standard" as "standart"?

Tags: orthography, esl, non-native-english

I've seen this incredibly often on StackOverflow, but also on a few other internet sites. "Standart" is an extremely common misspelling of "standard".

Is there a reason in how English is taught to non-native speakers, or another language which spells standard in this way, which results in the confusion?

Usually when I see this the rest of the conversation is otherwise flawless, which gives this an air of a careless mistake — e.g. confusing the English word with a cognate in another language. However, I don't know enough about other languages to tell if that's what's going on, or if it's something else.

Comment: Never seen this - you have even a single example to support the claim of commonness?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: This is the second one I've seen in the last two hours -- from different users: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6007214/revisions

Comment: Hm, with the one referenced I'm tempted to conjecture it is simply a mistake. The rest of the post shows that, while probably not a native speaker, they have a reasonably good grasp.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: See.. that's the interesting thing. Usually when I see this it is cases where the rest of the conversation is otherwise flawless. That makes me think there's another language where "standard" is a cognate to "standart" and it's a mistake -- but I don't know enough other languages to be sure.

Comment: @Billy: That makes a little more sense regarding cognates - maybe add such surrounding info to your question? I see people have already arrived at drawing on other languages, hopefully you'll get a solid answer; I just still can't relate that this is a common mistake.

Comment: Here are some better examples: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=standart

Comment: This is not a real answer, but the word was borrowed into Hebrew and is pronounced Standart. It is so commonly used I had to use a dictionary to find out what the original Hebrew word was. :)

Comment: "Why do non-native English users often spell "standard" as "standart"?" I am non-native English speaker and I don't do this mistake.

Comment: @Bogdan: That's why it says "often" not "always".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a common misspelling in German. The word also is "Standard" there, but as @Tim points out, "Standard" and "Standart" sound the same, and it is easy to mistakenly assume it's related to German "Art" (Way, manner, fashion).

I think this is a case where an error in the native language is repeated when those making it write in English.

Answer (score 32):

I don't think it's a very common mistake in general. In the case you quote, it is probably because *standard* is Стандарт in Russian, which ends with a **т**.

Answer (score 22):

In some languages, such as Russian and German, voiced consonant sounds at the end of a word change into their unvoiced counterparts, such as *d* to *t* and *g* to *k*. There is no Russian word ending with *д* and a *d* sound.

Comment: In German, this change is only in speaking, not in spelling (thus *der Standard* is spoken with a "t" sound, but spelled with "d").

Comment: @Paŭlo: Indeed, same goes with Russian, e.g. _хлеб_ (/xlʲep/). Sorry if my answer was unclear, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 10):

In Czech language, "standarta" means flag. "Standard" is commonly misspelled as "standart" even by native speakers, because they don't see the difference.

Answer (score 9):

In German, it's "die Standarte".  In Russian, it's стандарт (standart) - probably because the word was borrowed from German.

I've consulted four dictionaries to see how the word came into English, and they give four different origins!  So much for comparative etymology...
One of them, the Collins English Dictionary (10th ed., 2009) gives this as the source:

> C12: from Old French *estandart*  gathering place, flag to mark such a place, probably of Germanic origin; compare Old High German *stantan*  to stand, Old High German *ort*  place

Comment: In fact, the german word for standard (in the sense as published by standardizing organizations) is "der Standard". "Die Standarte" is a kind of flag. (There also is the composed word "die Standart" = "the way of standing", but this is almost never meant here.) In fact, "der Standard" is also often misspelled in German as "der Standart", which might then copy to English.

Comment: The English/German dictionary I (hurriedly) consulted didn't distinguish between the meanings of "standard", and I didn't think to look further.  Foolish of me.

Comment: In Hebrew it's also "Standart", and isn't limited to the last letter: "StandarTi" (as in "standard process"), or "StandarTim" (for "standards"). This isn't a mistake, either: "Standard" in Hebrew is plain wrong.

Comment: Both German "Standarte" and "Standard" are loan words, the first being much older than the latter. German "Standard" comes from the English "standard". Hebrew "standart" like most early modern Hebrew loan words from the west derives from German "Standard" pronounced with a "t" at the end.

Comment: "Standard" in English also means flag. So there you go.

Answer (score 1):

In Polish language, the proper word is "standard", but lots of people are pretty sure it's "standart" and that's how they write and speak. Because of many word endings, we can usually hear the difference between forms like "standardy" and "standarty" ("y" at the end makes it plural), but still most of the people aren't sure enough of which form is proper, so they don't object.

Comment: How exactly does this relate to the question about English that is under consideration?